# Beginner Questions: No movement? XAML - using WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

why does it not work the way it should? There is no movement.... below is the code:

```
namespace MovingBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Start_Animation(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myStoryboard.Begin();
        }

        private void MyAnimatedRectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Start_Animation(sender, e); 
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MovingBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">



<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" x:Key="myStoryboardKey">
                <DoubleAnimation
      Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedRectangle"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
      From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
      AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Rectangle Loaded="Start_Animation" x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle"
 Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" MouseDown="MyAnimatedRectangle_MouseDown" />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The myStoryBoard you are referring to in the Start_Animation method is a different one from the one in the XAML.

Here's a working version that searches for the storyboard resource:
Note that I removed the `Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();`

```
private void MyAnimatedRectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    PlayMyStoryboard(sender as FrameworkElement);
}

private void PlayMyStoryboard(FrameworkElement sender)
{
    var sb = sender.FindResource("myStoryboardKey") as Storyboard;
    if (sb != null)
    {
        sb.Begin();
    }
}

private void Start_Animation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PlayMyStoryboard(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I always try to avoid using `code-behind` (using `C#` instead of `XAML`) whenever I can and I would rather do it something like this. I am not sure if it has the exact behavior your wanted, but feel free to comment if you have any questions.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
                <Rectangle x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle"
                           Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue">
                    <Rectangle.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedRectangle"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"  AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"  />

                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Rectangle.Triggers>
                </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This might be helpful as well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you cannot access a resource inside your code by just assigning a x:Name. In the code behind what you have done you have created a new Storyboard. You have not assigned any existing storyboard inside the resource of the StackPanel.

To run this just name the stackpanel as in the code and just assign the resource to the storybard and used it

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="test">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" x:Key="myStoryboardKey">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedRectangle"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
                                 AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Rectangle Loaded="Start_Animation" 
                   x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle" 
                   Width="100" Height="100" 
                   Fill="Blue" Opacity="1" 
                   MouseDown="MyAnimatedRectangle_MouseDown" />

    </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
 myStoryboard = test.Resources["myStoryboardKey"] as Storyboard;
        myStoryboard.Begin();
```